# R two variables in stat_function

Tags: r

I created a dataframe inline with data argument of ggplot. I only needed *x* values and then I plotted the function y = x ^ 2.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x= seq(0, 10, by = 1)), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { x**2},
                geom = "line")
```

So this is a parabola, which is what I expected.

[image]

But what about if I want to plot all the solutions where *x* and *y* are both unknown but the solution is known? (I think this is called a Diophantine equation?) This time I put both an *x* and a *y* value into the data argument of ggplot, figuring I needed both. But my code just gives me a blank ggplot map without any line or anything in it.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x= seq(0, 10, by = 1), y = seq(0, 10, by = 1)), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { x + y = 2 }, 
                geom = "line")
```

But I think I should have a straight line here. When x = 0, y = 2. When x = 1, y = 1. When x = 2, y = 0...

[image]

I must be doing something wrong in the stat_function layer - is that right? How do I add another variable besides just an *x*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat_fun` is designed to draw functions, not to solve equations.
In this simple example, if `x + y = 2` then the function to draw is `y = f(x) = 2 - x`.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x= seq(0, 10, by = 1), y = seq(0, 10, by = 1)), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { 2 - x }, 
                geom = "line")
```

[image]

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. I see now that even in my parabola example, it's only drawing the positive x values because that is what I specified as the range, and it would look like a U if a said x= seq(-10, 10)